Azure DevOps Limitations with Enterprise Level Projects
I work for a large organization in QA and we use Azure DevOps for testing enterprise level projects. I have ran into some issues with projects this large and when I try to find solutions, all I've found are years old posts from Microsoft telling someone to submit it to their suggestions and then nothing happens. Thought maybe someone here might know a simpler way of doing things? Or an alternative to DevOps? I haven't used Jira in years, so I have no idea if it has these limitations.
The first issue we're having is that we can't track test execution tasks because you can't query them. They're not considered work objects. So I can't create a dashboard view from info we can't query. This means I get to manually click through test suites and visually identify the tests that are still out there needing to be ran, and who needs to run them. This is not feasible when you have 3k test executions in the first sprint of the project. You can query the test case, but that's not the execution task. A report of the people who made the scripts is not useful to us.
The second issue is with shared parameters. We would like to be able to have a variable or parameter as our test URL that the testers will click on in the first step of the test script. We would like it to be variable because the URL will change when we move to different environments. I have figured out how to do that with parameters, but it requires you to click on every single test and convert it to shared parameters. With the number of test cases we have, this would not be possible. I was looking for a way to assign shared parameters to all test cases, or maybe every new test case that was created. Also looked into copying that step to all test cases, but it would require working each test individually as well.
Is Azure DevOps actually enterprise level, or should we be looking for something else for project tracking? I work in state government if that is a factor in choosing the best test tracking method. We work with all divisions of the state.
Tried looking into Rest API, but it seemed like it would apply the parameter more like a configuration or tag, instead of adding the URL to the first test step and using it as a shared parameter.
Here's kinda what we're trying to accomplish:

Also tried using this edit feature to add parameters to multiple cases at once, but it just applies it like a tag or configuration or something, without making it a shared parameter (meaning we would still have to edit every test manually).
Screenshot of the edit menu in ADO:

Screenshot of parameter applied in history:



The first issue we're having is that we can't track test execution tasks because you can't query them.

You can check the Progress Report to test execution tasks. You can filter by Test Suites, Outcome, Configuration, Tester, Test Case Priority, and Test Case Assigned To. You can refer the details here.



The second issue is with shared parameters.

Based on your description, first, you want to use different URLs in different environments.
You can set multiple values ​​for the URL so that testers can choose the URL during testing in different environments. You can Add, edit, and rename your shared parameter sets in the Parameters page.

I understand that you want to assign shared parameters to all test cases or copy steps to all test cases. Maybe you can refer this Copy or clone test plans, test suites, and test cases. After you have configured some test cases well with the required shared parameters and shared steps, you can Copy it to the other test plan or test suits. This way, you don't need to configure every test case one by one.
Update

It's that I need to know which ones are unassigned out of the thousands we have.  We would also like to design a view in the dashboard where a tester will see all tests assigned to them.

You can consider using the OData queries with Power BI.
For example, with the following Power BI query, we can get the test points that are not assigned and create a report for it. You can refer this for more detailed steps and just replace the query with the following one.
= OData.Feed("https://analytics.dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_odata/v3.0-preview/TestPoints?"
        &"$apply=filter((TestSuite/TestPlanId eq {TestPlanId}))" 
        &"/groupby((TestPlanId, TestSuiteId, TestCaseId, Tester/UserName, AssignedTo/UserName, LastResultOutcome, LastResultState))", null, [Implementation="2.0"])



The issue with being able to query test case execution tasks isn't that we need to see pass/fail results. It's that I need to know which ones are unassigned out of the thousands we have. We would also like to design a view in the dashboard where a tester will see all tests assigned to them.
I will try copying the test cases and see if that brings over the shared parameters.

So copying them does work for the shared parameters. That should help quite a bit with existing scripts. With new scripts, however, we are using the CSV upload method due to the number of them (potentially thousands per sprint). So how would we add the shared parameters to all of them at once? Thank you for the assistance, btw.

Hi @BrianH, I updated the answer with the sample Power BI query to get the test points that are not assigned and create a report for it.

As to add the shared parameters, I tested and found that we can Copy
Test Plans, Import
Test Suites and Copy Test Cases with the shared parameters.

However, when importing test cases using the CSV, the exported test cases in the CSV doesn't contains the shared parameters, so they are not imported. I can understand your requirement. You can request the feature for Azure DevOps here to help the feature better.

Thank you so much for your time spent helping me here. I will submit a suggestion, and also look into this PowerBI stuff. I'm just starting out when it comes to that.

You can share the feature request here. So that others who have the same question can follow it and submit a vote.
